# Classification of surface curves?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, curves-and-surfaces

Having a genus $g$ closed orientable surface $\Sigma$ (connected sum of $g$ tori), how do I encode any embedded closed curve up to planar isotopy? For $g=1$ we can just state the coefficient $k \in \mathbb{Q} \cup \{\infty\}$, i.e. the coefficient of the line on the fundamental square (or as the $p/q$-curve. But how to do so for a general surface? Is this connected to the mapping class group $MCG(\Sigma)$?